# How to filter a dataframe using time series column

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe called df in the table below  with the following columns: "date" and also "Name". I intend to filter based on the "Date" column i.e. grouping based on each day in the "Date" column alongside the "Name" column and therefore counting the occurrence of each name occurring daily

```
 Date                           Name
"08/07/2017 10:10:58 0"         ABC
"08/07/2017 10:21:55 0"         DBF
"08/07/2017 11:21:55 0"         ABC
"08/08/2017 12:00:58 0"         ABC
"08/08/2017 12:10:58 0"         TTT
"08/09/2017 11:10:58 0"         TAC
"08/10/2017 11:20:58 0"         ABC
```

For Example: So iterating through the date column daily gives:

```
08/07/2017, ABC  2 
            DBF  1  

08/08/2017, ABC  1 

            TTT  1... till the last day
```

I don't know what loops I can use to help in grouping and counting.I have used the following codes:

```
df['Date' ]=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format= '"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S 0"')
df.index=df['Date']
del df['Date']
df.index=df['Date']
print(df)
df3=df.loc['2017-07-08 11:10:58':'2017-07-09 11:10:58'].value_counts
print(df3)
```

However,I keep  getting tracebacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
df['Date' ]= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format= '"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S 0"')
df = df.set_index(['Date'])
df3 = df.loc['2017-08-07 11:10:58':'2017-08-09 11:10:58']

df3 = (df3.groupby(df3.index.date)['Name']
         .value_counts()
         .rename_axis(('date','name'))
         .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df3)
         date name  count
0  2017-08-07  ABC      1
1  2017-08-08  ABC      1
2  2017-08-08  TTT      1
3  2017-08-09  TAC      1
```